# select data from excel spreadsheet that's read only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, excel, ssis, ssis-2005

I've got a dtsx package that selects data from an excel spreadsheet on the network and inserts it into a sql server table twice a day.  However, the process fails if someone is in the spreadsheet modifying data.  Is there a way to select data from an excel spreadsheet so that it doesn't fail if someone is in the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not used dtsx in anger in a long time but as an alternative solution.

Each time the job runs, would it be possible to create a temporary copy of that spreasheet (via your dtsx package) and then you can use that copy instead to import the data into table. When your done with the copy you can simply remove it.

Comment: yeah, i guess that works.  didn't really want to do that but ah well.